# What sort of literary device is "for tomorrow will be anxious for itself" in Matthew 6:34?

Tags: matthew

**Matthew 6:34**

> "Therefore do not be anxious about tomorrow, **for tomorrow will be anxious for itself.** Sufficient for the day is its own trouble." ESV My emphasis.

If "tomorrow" is not alive how can it be anxious?

What sort of literary device is being employed here?

What does this figure of speech achieve?

RE: this verse another question on this site asks if worrying is a sin but does not mention literary devices or figures of speech.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Anthropomorphism is the attribution of human traits, emotions, or intentions to non-human entities. It is considered to be an innate tendency of human psychology.

[Wikipedia- Anthropomorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anthropomorphism)

By shifting the worry of tomorrow to tomorrow itself, one is relieved of the worry.

That the Lord himself enjoins us to do so, dispels any sense of being 'irresponsible' in so doing. For that is the usual argument about such things, that we 'must' worry about the morrow as it is our 'duty' to do so.

But that the Lord himself shifts anxiety off our shoulders and places it firmly on the morrow itself, is a great source of comfort.

Comment: +1 Exactly my thoughts.

Answer (score 1):

Matt 6:34 uses a literary device known as anthropomorphism (sometimes also called, personification) where the "day" or "tomorrow" is given sentience by means of worrying.  It MAY have quoted a common aphorism of the time.  The verse in question is in two halves and here is the BLB literal translation, but set out in its two halves:

> Therefore do not worry about tomorrow, **for tomorrow will worry about
> itself.**
>
> Sufficient to the day is its own trouble.

The first half is fairly self explanatory; but the two halves explain each other - one being an amplification of the other.  It is the second that presents difficulties for moderns like us but when understood helps to explain the first half.  Most modern versions provide a smoothed out and slightly interpretive translation which are all credible such as:

- NIV, NASB, CSB, HCSB, ISV: for tomorrow will worry about itself. Each day has enough trouble of its own.
- NLT: Today’s trouble is enough for today.
- BSB, NET: Today has enough trouble of its own.
- GNT: There is no need to add to the troubles each day brings.
- Tyndale, "For the day present hath ever enough of his own trouble."

Of these I prefer the NIV, NASB, CSB, HCSB, ISV.  Jesus is simply saying that we should leave tomorrow's worries for tomorrow and do not add unneeded worries for today.  Good advice!  This same aphorism survives in modern maxims such as:

- I will worry about it then.
- Let us not cross the bridge before we come to it
- That is tomorrow's concern
- etc, etc.

Barnes sets this context:

> **The morrow shall take thought** - The morrow will have anxieties and cares of its own, but it will also bring the proper provision for
> those cares. Though you will have needs, yet God will provide for them
> as they occur. Do not, therefore, increase the cares of today by
> borrowing trouble from the future. Do your duty faithfully now, and
> depend upon the mercy of God and his divine help for the troubles
> which are yet to come.

Answer (score 0):

> What sort of literary device is "for tomorrow will be anxious for itself" in Matthew 6:34?

It is doubtful that this expression instantiates a literary device. Furthermore, this translation is less intelligible than NRSV: "*for tomorrow will bring worries of its own*". KJV would be placed in the midpoint ("*for the morrow shall take thought for the things of itself*") despite the fact that it employs the neutral, wider-encompassing term "*thought*" instead of "*worries*" or "*anxious*".

This is one example of how translations tend to distort the substance of a text which in and of itself is enigmatic or rather outright flawed.

> If "tomorrow" is not alive how can it be anxious?

The excerpt from ESV is most emphatic in the mistaken suggestion that "tomorrow" is an entity.

Without knowing the Koine version, from the passage altogether it is reasonable to infer that "tomorrow" is to be interpreted as a circumstantial complement of time. The excerpt can be paraphrased as "*tomorrow there will be other/unexpected/unrelated worries*" or "*other worries will ensue tomorrow*". This preempts the mistaken approach of attributing to "tomorrow" a state that can be attributed only to entities.

Comment: ESV maintains literal idioms or figures, which is very essential to understand the literature.

Comment: @Michael16 I hear you, but the OP's 2nd question reflects that forcing a literal expression in the ESV translation accomplished the opposite of understanding that excerpt.

Comment: It's forcing accurate translation. The reason for literary illiteracy among men is only due to lack of reading figurative language. The less they read the more questions and difficulties when they face it.